# How can I improve NumberString?

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, number-representation

I would like to test strings to see if they represent numbers. This should include number representations with precision marks and scientific notation. `NumberString` is unfortunately more restrictive:

```
mylist = {"1.23", "1.23`", "1.23*^4", "Print[fail]"};

StringMatchQ[mylist, NumberString]
(* {True, False, False, False} *)
```

As a complication, I want to avoid converting the strings to expressions and testing with `NumberQ`, as some strings may contain code which is unsafe to evaluate.

How can I make a pattern like `NumberString` but which matches all of the first three elements in `mylist`?

Comment: Are you going to self-answer?  I may dig into this if not.

Comment: Also, is your reason for not converting to expressions *only* for safety as stated?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, no, I'm not planning to self answer. Yes, safety is basically the only reason - it would be okay to create a held expression for example.

Comment: "*I would like to test strings to see if they represent numbers.*" How strict are we talking here? Do you want the string `"EulerGamma"` to be considered a number, or are you referring to number in the sense of `NumberQ`?

Comment: @ChipHurst, for my needs I just need to handle explicit numbers with precision marks and scientific notation, though if you have a method that can handle named constants too it would be interesting to see it. My original problem was to examine the box form of expressions and determine whether strings containing a backtick were numbers or symbols with context marks. I was surprised to discover that `NumberString` didn't work for this.

Comment: Simon, I updated my answer with what I think is a much cleaner pattern.  Would you please test it?  If it passes I'll probably remove the old one entirely.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, the new pattern is definitely cleaner and it appears to work perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Edit:* I came to realize that my original form was redundant.  I now propose this instead:

```
p2 = 
  NumberString ~~ "" | "`" | ("`" | "``" ~~ NumberString) ~~ 
    "" | ("\\*^" | "\\*^-" ~~ DigitCharacter ..);
```

Test:

```
test = {"1.23`4.56*^-7", "1.23", "1.23`", "1.23``5", "1.23*^4", "Print[fail]"};

StringMatchQ[test, p2]
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, True, True, False}
> ```

Comment: Actually you should write `"\\*^"`, otherwise for example `"1.23abc*^4"` matches also `True` ! which is annoying for safety reasons !!

Comment: @SquareOne Right, sorry guys.

Comment: I confirm you need 2 backslashes `"\\*^"` not `"\*^"`

Comment: @SquareOne Yuck!  Of course.  I really made a mess of this.  Thanks.  I'm not sure that is the only problem however.

Comment: Okay now I'm puzzled - why are **two** backslashes required?

Comment: @Simon I believe there is a question about this.  IIRC it may be a version-related issue.

Comment: @Simon Related, but not what I'm remembering: [(7258)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7258/121)

Comment: @Simon The `\\*` is in to documentation and I quoted it myself here: [(6999)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6999/121).  However I *still* think I remember something funny about this that I can't find right now.  Anyway I'm getting tired and making foolish mistakes so I'll stop now.

Comment: Shouldn't we also match strings that specify accuracy, e.g. `"1.23``4"`?

Comment: @Chip Yet another thing I forgot.  I'll fix that one later.

Comment: @Chip I think I addressed that.  If you find any other problems please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

`RegularExpression` may be helpful, like this

```
In[109]:= 
mylist = {"1.23", "1.23`", "1.23*^4", "1.22*^-2", "Print[fail]"};
numberString = 
  RegularExpression[
    "[0-9]*.?[0-9]*`?"] | (RegularExpression["[0-9]*.?[0-9]*`?"] ~~ 
     "*^" ~~ RegularExpression["-?[0-9]+"]);
StringMatchQ[mylist, numberString]
Do[StringMatchQ[mylist, NumberString], {10^5}] // AbsoluteTiming
Do[StringMatchQ[mylist, numberString], {10^5}] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[111]= {True, True, True, True, False}

Out[112]= {0.607035, Null}

Out[113]= {0.917052, Null}
```

Comment: See comments on Mr Wizard's answer regarding "*" acting as a wildcard

Answer (score 4):

I'm not certain how general it is, but works :)

Just for fun, I've assumed that FrontEnd should know what is a number and what to split on boxes:

```
StringFreeQ[#, LetterCharacter] && c[#][[1, 1]] === # & /@ {

 "1.23", "1.23`", "1.23*^4", "Print[fail]", "string", "1`1", "1`1`1"}
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, False, False, True, False}
> ```

Where `c` is [`UndocumentedTestFEParser`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13371/5478) generously introduced to us by [John Fultz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/309/john-fultz):

```
c = MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[#, True]] &
```

Comment: This looks very interesting. My original problem came from analysing boxes so this sort of approach might fit nicely.

Comment: @SimonWoods :) great. Good luck then.