# How to check String format?

Tags: string-manipulation

How can I check if the string contains a real or integer number, space and string?

e.g. 
`StrCheck["156 af"] = true`
`StrCheck["15.6 af"] = true`

`StrCheck["a 156 af"] = false` 
`StrCheck["a 1.56 af"] = false`

Thank you!

Comment: Your examples are not really conclusive. What are the criteria for the decision?

Comment: StringMatchQ[string,DigitCharacter .. ~~ __]?

Comment: StringMatchQ[rhs, DigitCharacter .. ~~ ___ ~~ LetterCharacter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = StringMatchQ[#, NumberString ~~ " " ~~ __] &;

f /@ {"156 af", "15.6 af", "a 156 af", "a 1.56 af"}
```

> {True, True, False, False}

See [`StringMatchQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringMatchQ.html), [`StringExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringExpression.html), [`NumberString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberString.html), [`BlankSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankSequence.html), [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html), [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html)

Related: [How can I improve NumberString?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73172/121)