# How to read a part of huge matrix saved in a TXT file as single expression?

Tags: performance-tuning, import, text, parsing

I saved a huge matrix of numbers with dimensions `{400, 4001, 2}` using `Put` and got a TXT file formatted in the following way:

```
{{{1.1, 1.2}, {1.8,
0.3}, {2.1, 0.7},
<...>
{1257.9, -3.6*^-8}, {1258.2, 
-3.4*^-9}}}
```

Actually I have hundreds of such files. Is there a smart way to read only a part of the matrix efficiently? For example, how to take the first 20 or 40 sub-arrays out of 400? Simple `Import` or `Get` on the whole file takes too much time.

Here is one of my files: [link](http://www.filedropper.com/eigf-v110-v20000).

Any suggestion to better save data in the future is welcome.

Comment: It would seem easier to read all of it in, the use `Part` on the imported result. The amount of data to read in seems modest.

Comment: Thank you but I have hundreds of files, the single Readlist takes about 12 sec, there should be a quicker way to do it but I can't see it now.

Comment: Are all the numbers written to the same precision? For example, are they all 3 ASCII characters (2 numbers plus a decimal point)? If so, you might be able to jump to the appropriate spot in the file with a binary read.

Comment: Would you be able to post a link to one of the files for us to test out different import strategies?

Comment: They are not of the same lenght, as an example:
{{{1.5707963267948966, 2.886750801321724*^-6}, {1.8849555921538759, 
0.00003053776721007641}, {2.199114857512855, 0.00006931880488431765}, ...},...}. When I saved, I had a big matrix and I used Put to create a txt file. One file is 70MB, is it really useful to put it online?

Comment: have you tried `Get` and `Import(..,"Package")` ?  You also ought to show how you are using `ReadList`.    Also,also if you need to repeatedly access different parts of the files consider a one time conversion to a binary format.

Comment: I've tried `Get` with about the same `Timing` result (to be hotest it is 20% faster). I don't know how to use  `Import(..,"Package") ` . My aim is simply: in that file I have 400 functions {{{x1,f1(x1)},{x2,f1(x2)},...}, {{x1,f2(x1)},{x2,f2(x2)},...},... {{x1,f400(x1)},{x2,f400(x2)},...}}. I would like to take the first 20,30 or 40 only.

Comment: `Import` should have square brackets.. sorry about that, (using my kids keyboard!).  I doubt it is any faster anyway though.

Answer (score 3):

### Number counting approach

Since your file contains (with rare exceptions) only 3 numbers on each line and the data has dimensions `{400,4001,2}`, it is possible to calculate how many lines you should read in order to obtain the first 40 sets out of 400.

At first, some checks:

```
data = << "EigF-V1_1.0-V2_0.000.txt";
Dimensions[data]
```

> ```
> {400, 4001, 2}
> ```

```
linesString = ReadList["D:/desktop/EigF-V1_1.0-V2_0.000.txt", "String"];

Length[linesString]
```

> ```
> 1066932
> ```

```
lengths = Table[
   Length[StringCases[
     line, (NumberString ~~ "*^" ~~ NumberString) | NumberString]], {line, 
    linesString}];

Tally[lengths]
```

> ```
> {{3, 1066925}, {4, 6}, {1, 1}}
> ```

So we see that there are only 4 lines containing 4 numbers and only one (the last) line with single number.

You need 40 sets each containing `4001*2 = 8002` numbers. So you need `40*8002 = 320080` numbers which occupy approximately `320080/3 = 106693` lines. These lines can contain more than 320080 numbers because some lines contain 4 numbers.

Now you should proceed as follows with your files (assuming that they have the same structure):

```
linesString = 
  ReadList["D:/desktop/EigF-V1_1.0-V2_0.000.txt", "String", 106693];

numbers = StringCases[
   linesString, (NumberString ~~ "*^" ~~ NumberString) | NumberString];

Length[Flatten@numbers]
```

> ```
> 320081
> ```

We need only the first 320080 numbers:

```
numbers = Take[Flatten@numbers, 320080];
```

Now we just need to recreate the array:

```
dataArray = ArrayReshape[numbers, {40, 4001, 2}];
```

That's all.

P.S. In the above solution I assumed that your file doesn't contain numbers with precision marks like `` 1.23` ``, `` 1.23`20 `` or ``` 0.``20 ```. If your file does contain such numbers you should use more involved pattern for matching them than the pattern `(NumberString ~~ "*^" ~~ NumberString) | NumberString` I used above. You can take such patterns from [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73172/280) (I haven't tested myself).

---

### Closing braces counting approach

This approach is much more efficient and robust than the previous and doesn't depend on the knowledge of the structure of your file (like how many numbers you have on one line). It also automatically supports all `InputForm` *Mathematica* numbers including numbers with precision marks. The idea is to read the file line-by-line and count closing braces until you get as many sets as you need. It is possible because every set contains `4001 + 1 = 4002` closing braces according to `Dimensions` of your data. After finishing we truncate the last line dropping everything after the last closing brace, then add one additional closing brace at the end in order to form complete and valid *Mathematica* expression.

The variable `nSetsToTake` determines how many sets you wish to take:

```
str = OpenRead["EigF-V1_1.0-V2_0.000.txt"];

nSetsToTake = 40;
nBraces = nSetsToTake*(4001 + 1);

count = 0;
lines = Reap[
    While[(count += StringCount[Sow[Read[str, "String"]], "}"]) < 
      nBraces]][[2, 1]];
Close[str];
pos = StringPosition[lines[[-1]], "}"];
lines[[-1]] = StringTake[lines[[-1]], First@pos[[nBraces - count - 1]]];
dataArray = ToExpression[StringJoin[lines] <> "}", InputForm];
Dimensions@dataArray
```

> ```
> {40, 4001, 2}
> ```

---

### How to increase accessibility of your data

> Any suggestion to better save data in the future is welcome.

It looks like you have created you file with *Mathematica*. For the future I recommend instead of saving the whole data array as a single expression, to `Write` each of the sets as a separate expression ending with a new line, for example as follows:

```
str = OpenWrite[];
Do[Write[str, set], {set, dataArray}];
Close[str];
```

Now you can easily get as many sets as you need in a very efficient way, for example taking the first 4 sets:

```
dataSet = ReadList[%, "Expression", 4];

Dimensions[dataSet]
```

> ```
> {4, 4001, 2}
> ```