# How to get the longest bracket pairs from a string

Tags: string-manipulation, parsing, regular-expressions

In *C#*, we can use regular expression to do some balancing groups, like we can get

```
{<aa <bbb> <bbb> aa>, <<dfa>a>}
```

from

```
"xx <aa <bbb> <bbb> aa> yy<<dfa>a>"
```

using the regular expression

```
<((?<gro><)|(?<-gro>>)|[^<>])*(?(gro)(?!))>
```

We can get the syntax coloring with for instance [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/):

[image]

How to realize this in *Mathematica*?

I prefer using regular expression to do this, but *Mathematica* just supports some basic usage in regular expressions, and doesn't support advanced usage such as dynamic regular expression and balancing groups.

PS: Another example: how to get `{[ab*[c]d], (b(x99))}` from `"dd9[ab*[c]d]esiddx(45x(b(x99))"`?

Comment: Do you mean in an expression,  in a string, in a notebook? Or something else?

Comment: @mikado In a string

Comment: Just to summarize this question: The .NET flavor of regular expressions has a unique feature called "balancing groups". How can the same thing be achieved in *Mathematica*, which uses another flavor of regular expressions?

Comment: @C.E. We can do it by any method,I just want to use regular expressions more. :)

Comment: Assuming you are trying to match the highlighted angle brackets expression above, the following piece of code does the job (although it requires applying twice the relevant function):    `StringReplace[
 StringReplace[str, RegularExpression["(\\<[a-z]+\\>)+?"] :> "*"], 
 RegularExpression["(\\<.+?\\>)"] :> "*"]` where _str_ is the expression to match.

Comment: Also, regarding the later example, `StringCases[str, RegularExpression["(.+)\\+(.+)"] :> {"$1", "$2"}][[-1]]` again does the trick... but I'm somehow not sure that this is what you are looking for

Comment: @user42582 The longest bracket pairs?

Comment: @yode: would you care to elaborate?

Comment: @user42582 I have failure to do it.

Comment: Strongly related: "[String matching balanced pairs of braces](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87329/280)."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**First Case**

```
str = "xx <aa <bbb> <bbb> aa> yy<<dfa>a>";
StringCases[str, 
   RegularExpression["(?P<a><([^<>]|(?P>a))*>)"]
]
(* {"<aa <bbb> <bbb> aa>", "<<dfa>a>"} *)
```

This works as follows:

- `(?P<a> ...)` names `a` the pattern `<([^<>]|(?P>a))*>`.
- The string or substring matching this pattern must start with `<` and end with `>`.
- Within these characters, the pattern `([^<>]|(?P>a))` can be repeated 0 or more times.
- This subpattern says that no character can be `<` or `>`. If such a character is met while reading the string, then the pattern `a` is called by `(?P>a)` and we start again at bullet 2 with the substring starting with this character.

**Second Case**

```
str2 = "dd9[ab*[c]d]esiddx(45x(b(x99))"
StringCases[str2, 
   RegularExpression["(?P<a>(\\[|\\()([^\\[\\]\\(\\)]|(?P>a))*(\\]|\\)))"]
]
(* {"[ab*[c]d]", "(b(x99))"} *)
```

This works as above. Here, instead of `<` at the beginning of the (sub)string, we allow for `[` or `(` with `(\\[|\\()`. The other modifications are in line with this change.

Note that this regular expression may not be satisfying for cases such as

```
str3 = "dd9[ab*[c]d)esiddx(45x(b(x99))";
(* The square bracket after d is replaced by a parenthesis. *)

StringCases[str3, 
   RegularExpression["(?P<a>(\\[|\\()([^\\[\\]\\(\\)]|(?P>a))*(\\]|\\)))"]
]
(* {"[ab*[c]d)", "(b(x99))"} *)
```

The first element starts with a `[` and ends with `)`. This can be avoided by adding a pattern and a condition test on this pattern:

```
StringCases[str3, 
   RegularExpression["(?P<a>((?P<b>\\[)|\\()([^\\[\\]\\(\\)]|(?P>a))*(?(b)\\]|\\)))"]
]
(* {"[c]", "(b(x99))"} *)
```

The starting `[` is referred to as `b`. The pattern `(?(b)\\]|\\))` tells us that if `b` had a match, then the character to match should be `]`, or otherwise `)`.

Comment: (+100) [Related answer by WReach](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72739/280) which is worthy to read along with this.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks for the bounty!

Comment: Also strongly related: ["Match opening and closing parentheses?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77808/280)

Answer (score 7):

This works:

```
str = "xx <aa <bbb> <bbb> aa> yy<<dfa>a>";

StringCases[str, "<" ~~ Shortest@s___ ~~ ">" /; StringCount[s, "<"] == StringCount[s, ">"]]
```

> ```
> {"<aa <bbb> <bbb> aa>", "<<dfa>a>"}
> ```

Or equivalently

```
StringCases[str, 
 s : RegularExpression["<.*?>"] /; StringCount[s, "<"] == StringCount[s, ">"]]
```

> ```
> {"<aa <bbb> <bbb> aa>", "<<dfa>a>"}
> ```

Of course it isn't a pure regex approach: the method uses `Condition`. Similar approach is used in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121855/280) answer of mine where an extended explanation of joint working of `Condition` together with *lazy* quantifier `Shortest` (or `*?` in regex) is given.

---

The second problem can be solved using two patterns of the same type as alternatives:

```
Clear[balanced]
balanced[{l_, r_}] := 
 HoldPattern[(left : l ~~ Shortest@s___ ~~ right : r) /; 
   StringCount[s, left] == StringCount[s, right]]

str2 = "dd9[ab*[c]d]esiddx(45x(b(x99))";

StringCases[str2, balanced /@ {{"[", "]"}, {"(", ")"}}]
```

> ```
> {"[ab*[c]d]", "(b(x99))"}
> ```

Or we can combine them into single pattern as follows:

```
StringCases[str2, (left : "[" | "(" ~~ Shortest@s___ ~~ right : "]" | ")") /; 
  MatchQ[{left, right}, {"[", "]"} | {"(", ")"}] && 
   StringCount[s, left] == StringCount[s, right]]
```

> ```
> {"[ab*[c]d]", "(b(x99))"}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Not a regular expression but counting the left and right separators to find positions where they're equal in number can find top level bracket pairs:

```
str1 = "xx<aa<bbb> <bbb>aa>yy<<dfa>a>";
str2 = "dd9[ab*[c]d]esiddx(45x(b(x99))";

f[l_, r_, str_] := Module[{sum, pos},
   sum = Accumulate[StringCases[str, l | r] /. {l -> 1, r -> -1}];
   pos = First /@ StringPosition[str, (l | r)];
   Partition[(First /@ 
       SplitBy[Transpose[{sum, pos}], #[[1]] == 0 &])[[All, 2]], 2]
   ];
```

Works for strings with complete pairs:

```
f["<", ">", str1]
f["[", "]", str2]
{{3, 19}, {22, 29}}
{{4, 12}}
```

But does not work for e.g. `f["(", ")", str2]`because `str2` has one more opening `(` than `)`.

Comment: (+1) I used similar technique in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/117678/280) answer (section "Closing braces counting approach").

Answer (score 0):

My original answer (seen in the comments) was based on the simple idea that you can first identify the bracketed expressions at the last (deeper) level (so to speak) and then progress 'upwards' by matching bracketed expressions one level up, by applying pattern matching **based on regular expressions** sequentially, as many times as there are levels of enclosed bracketed terms.

The original code did this for the demo string

`str="xx <aa <bbb> <bbb> aa> yy<<dfa>a>"`

by first identifying the inner bracketed expressions by means of

`tmp=StringReplace[str, RegularExpression["(\\<[a-z]+\\>)+?"] :> "*"]`

After the execution of the above code, *tmp* contains the following string

`tmp="xx <aa * * aa> yy<*a>"`

where an asterisk ('*') denotes successful matching.

Now, since there is another level of brackets, the approach is to apply the pattern matching once more as in:

`StringReplace[tmp, RegularExpression["(\\<.+?\\>)"] :> "*"]`

which outputs

`"xx * yy*"`

Note, once more, how the asterisks match bracketed expressions at this 'upper' level of the initial expression.

Therefore, it seems plausible to be able to construct a recursive pattern matching function (not presented here) that is based on regular expressions that performs the required task.