# How to make RawBoxes to be Expression

Tags: front-end, formatting, expression-construction

```
expr = First@
  Level[Values@
    WolframLanguageData["Plot", 
     EntityProperty["WolframLanguageSymbol", 
      "DocumentationExampleInputs"]], {3}]
```

> Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}]

But I find the `Head` of `expr` is `RawBoxes`

```
Head@expr
(* RawBoxes *)
```

And I cannot get the string like `"Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,6 Pi}]"`

```
ToString@expr
(* "RawBoxes[Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{Plot, [, RowBox[{RowBox[{Sin, 
[, x, ]}], ,, RowBox[{{, RowBox[{x, ,, 0, ,, RowBox[{6, Pi}]}], 
}}]}], ]}]], Input, ShowStringCharacters -> True]]" *)
```

Comment: Did you look at `MakeExpression` or `ToExpression`?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Yes,I have.And fail to make it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually `MakeExpression` works.
If you want to evaluate that expression,

```
expr//ToBoxes//MakeExpression//ReleaseHold
```

will work. If you want to get similar output as Wjx

```
(expr // ToBoxes // MakeExpression) /. ExpressionCell[a_, __] :> a
```

Answer (score 2):

Will this help?

```
Cases[Hold[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}]], ExpressionCell[cont_, ___] :> Hold@cont, Infinity]
```

> {Hold[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 [Pi]}]]}

A trick using `Cases` to extract stuffs in a Held Expression. Is this what you need? :)

Also, if your real application needs you to convert them into a string:

```
Cases[Hold[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}]], 
  ExpressionCell[cont_, ___] :> ToString@Unevaluated@cont, 
  Infinity][[1]]
```

> "Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}]"

Answer (score 1):

A solution that is not very satisfactory is to grab the argument of `BoxData` and turn that into an expression.

```
expr = First@
  Level[Values@
    WolframLanguageData["Plot", 
     EntityProperty["WolframLanguageSymbol", 
      "DocumentationExampleInputs"]], {3}]
FirstCase[expr, BoxData[data_]:>data,,Infinity]//ToExpression
```

(one can also use `MakeExpression[#,StandardForm]&` instead of `ToExpression` to get a held expression).

Comment: I cannot very understand your `FirstCase`.Have you see [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125391/how-to-get-the-longest-bracket-pairs-from-a-string)?

Comment: The goal is to extract the argument of `BoxData` in `expr`.  The pattern `BoxData[_]` matches `BoxData` with any single argument; I've named that argument `data`.  Then `:>` introduces a rule, whose right-hand side is `data`, meaning that I extract the argument I've named `data`.  The empty argument (between commas) is the default value used in case `BoxData[_]` did not match anything in your `expr`, and the `Infinity` describes at which levels to operate.  Contrarily to your other question here we are working with expressions and not just strings so no difficulty matching paired delimiters.