# Problem with conversion of UI controllers' boxes to expressions

Tags: bugs, expression-manipulation, conversion, boxes

**Bug introduced in V10 and partially fixed in V11.1.1**

---

### TLDR

Various of expressions which have fancy typeset form or are designed as UI elements won't survive `ToExpression @* ToBoxes` round-trip. And they should.

### Examples

- `InterpolatingFunction` (*new*)

  ```
  MakeExpression[#, StandardForm] & @ ToBoxes @ Interpolation[
      {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 0}}
  ] // Shallow
  ```

  > ```
  > ErrorBox[ErrorBox[TagBox[<<5>>]]]
  > ```
  >
  > ToExpression::esntx: Could not parse TagBox[<<1>>] as input.
- `InputField`

  ```
  ToExpression @ ToBoxes @ InputField[Dynamic[x]]
  ```

  > ```
  >  $Failed
  > ```
  >
  > ToExpression::notstrbox: InputFieldBox[x] is not a string or a box. ToExpression can only interpret strings or boxes as Wolfram Language input.

  I don't expect `InputField[Dynamic[x]]` but at least something which is a proper expression, e.g. button works:

  ```
  ToExpression @ ToBoxes @ Button[Dynamic[x]] // InputForm
  ```

  > ```
  > Button[Dynamic[x], Evaluator -> None, Appearance -> Automatic, Method -> "Preemptive"]
  > ```

  Things get weirder, `MakeExpression` can handle `InputField` case:

  ```
  InputForm @ MakeExpression[
      #,
      StandardForm
  ] & @ ToBoxes @ InputField[Dynamic[x]]
  ```

  > ```
  > HoldComplete[InputField[Dynamic[x]]]
  > ```
- `FileNameSetter`

  ```
  InputForm@MakeExpression[
    #,
    StandardForm
  ] & @ ToBoxes @ FileNameSetter[Dynamic[x]]
  ```

  > ```
  > ErrorBox[RowBox[{"FileNameSetterBoxes", "[", ErrorBox[Dynamic[x]], ",", "Open", ",", All, "]"}]]
  > ```
  >
  > Syntax::sntxf: "FileNameSetterBoxes[" cannot be followed by "x,Open,All]".

### Question

Are those bugs or have I missed something. Please help me understand that. :)

---

#### related

[ToExpression and ToBoxes aren't inverses of each other?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/112491/5478)

[How to make RawBoxes to be Expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125403/5478)

Comment: `x = Dynamic[y]; MakeExpression@MakeBoxes@FileNameSetter[x]` and `x = Dynamic[y]; ToExpression@MakeBoxes@FileNameSetter[x]` do work.

Comment: I think this should be tagged [tag:bugs], because `MakeExpression@MakeBoxes@FileNameSetter[Dynamic[f]]` and `ToExpression@ToBoxes@FileNameSetter[Dynamic[f]]` works in Mathematica version 9.0.1.

Comment: @Karsten7. thanks for checking! I agree but I wanted to ask community.

Comment: In version 9 `ToBoxes@FileNameSetter[Dynamic[f]]` creates an `InterpretationBox`. Since version 10 a `TemplateBox` is created.

Comment: For the `FileNameSetter` case the explanation could simply be that the proper definition for `MakeExpression[
 TemplateBox[{name_, type_, filter_}, "FileNameSetterBoxes"], StandardForm]` is missing. Do `FileNameSetterBoxes` even exist?

Comment: @Karsten7. The definition *does* exist.  But it's in the stylesheet.  I.e., `CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "FileNameSetterBoxes"}]`.  Which the FE understands, but the kernel does not.  So this does properly roundtrip to output cells and back to input cells, but not through the more constrained `MakeBoxes`/`MakeExpression` roundtrip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A support case with the identification [CASE:3706792] was created.

- `InputField`

  > [...] This is an issue with `ToExpression`. I have brought it to the attention the relevant developers and they are further investigating the issue. [...]

  **Bug introduced in V10 and persisting through V11.1.1**
- `FileNameSetter`

  > [...] the issue for FileNameSetter is different than in the other cases [...]

  **Bug introduced in V10 and fixed V11.1.1**