# FormPage oddities

Tags: front-end, gui-construction, wolfram-cloud

1. problem with default value

   > `FormPage[{namespec -> type -> default, ...}, func ]` uses `default` as the default for the field specified by `namespec`.

   ```
   CloudDeploy[#, Permissions -> "Public"] & @ FormPage[
      "country" -> "Country" -> "CH"
    , GeoGraphics[#country] &
   ]
   ```

   I see Berlin, certainly not Switzerland. But ok, one can say it is a default value, not the initial one. Sure, but Berlin map stays there if you submit an empty field.

   `FormFunction` documentation allows *type* to be a string, here `"Country"`, but let's use association form: `<|"Interpreter" -> "Country"`.

   Still Berlin.

   Full syntax with an initial value seems to work fine:

   ```
   fullFormPage = FormPage[
       "country" -> <|"Interpreter" -> "Country", "Input" -> "CH"|> -> "CH"
     , GeoGraphics[#country] &
   ]
   ```
2. problem with typesetting

   ```
   InputForm /@ {
    fullFormPage,
    ToExpression @ ToBoxes @ fullFormPage
   } // Column
   ```

   > FormPage[FormObject[<|"country" -> ...|>|>], GeoGraphics[#country] & ]
   >   FormPage[FormObject[<|"country" -> ...|>, <||>], GeoGraphics[#country] & ]

   `<||>` appeared in `FormObject`, there is no error because it is a valid `OptionsPattern[]`, and I wouldn't mind but a `FormPage` of this form misbehaves even for fully specified field:

   ```
    CloudDeploy[ ToExpression @ ToBoxes @ fullFormPage, Permissions -> "Public"]
   ```

   Berlin again...

---

Am I misusing `Form*` functions? Are those documentation's bugs or just bugs

> CASE:3892750

p.s. related:

[Problem with conversion of UI controllers' boxes to expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125587/5478)

[Wolfram Cloud deployment guidelines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123894/5478)

[Using CloudDeploy with dependent functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125837/5478)

Comment: If you need a temporary work-around supplying `"Input"->"CH"` works, but it still doesn't work with the blank field. I agree that looks like a bug with handling the `"Default"` parameter.

Comment: @MB1965 yep, there is a bug with not handling default value, and some inconsistency because I see an initial (wrong) plot while for "name"->"spec" there isn't any map at all. So far I know the report was forwarded to developers.

Comment: I think the initial wrong plot may actually be coming from this `GeoGraphics["CH"]`. Which gives an error and my current location (yours must be Berlin). Try providing the full entity as the default value. And give `"Input"->"CH"` as the input value for the users.

Comment: It seems it simply doesn't apply the `Interpreter` to the default value. Useful to know, but also a definite potential stumbling block.

Comment: @MB1965 Yep probably. And yes, I know the full syntax behaves correctly but documentation shows examples where I don't have to specify full interpreter input or Entity objects. So while not critical, it is still a bug.

Comment: Does it have any where the `Interpreter` is applied to the default value? Haven't seen that one.

Comment: @MB1965 Does it have it isn't? I'd agree in case where the whole flow is clear. But they only give an impression of how things work and what to expect.

Comment: The only one I saw was like `spec->"Number"->3` and of course it's ambiguous there. They ought to make it explicit that it doesn't apply, I agree.