# How to restore a Notebook saved as Package?

Tags: notebooks, packages, conversion

A Notebook I was working on was saved as `"Package"` (with the extension ".m"). Upon opening this file, everything is unreadable.

How do I convert this file back to the Notebook format (with the extension ".nb")?

[image]

[image]

Check the top bar. It says Xcode instead of *Mathematica*.

[image: Opening with mathematica]

Comment: I wonder if `Notebook/.{".m"->".nb"}` would work?

Comment: Guys I have aded the picture of the content of the file.

Comment: Open the file with _Mathematica_...

Comment: @Xavier Yes it is a mathematica file.

Comment: @Xavier I still get gibberish.

Comment: We want the gibberish in _Mathematica_, not Xcode.

Comment: @Xavier I'll post it now

Comment: @Xavier As can be seen, there are only a portion of readable content. The rest of the content is 'gibberish'

Comment: I bet the "gibberish" portion is some compressed image.  Probably best to upload your .m file somewhere so someone can help you make it an openable .nb file.

Comment: Direct me please.@QuantumDot

Comment: Press `File` in the top bar, then `Save As...`, and select `.nb` as the file extension. If you open the `.nb` file, everything will be in Text style. Select the cells you want to convert to code style, and press Alt+9.

Comment: I have uploaded my file onto 
http://www.filedropper.com/osflabreport1

Comment: @JHM I have saved it as .nb but there are still 'gibberish'

Comment: I'm just taking whatever screen shot I'm seeing that isn't making any sense to me so that someone might be able to help me.

Comment: I don't want to sound 'lazy' but I've been working on this the entire day and I'm a math and physics student by training. Would you go further to assist me by uploading the 'proper' file on a site?

Comment: Have you managed to open it in Mathematica instead of Xcode as @JHM suggested?  Right click on the file, then "Open With...", pick Mathematica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you could auto-extract separately the images and the text from your `"Package"` file.

First we need to uncomment the commented lines in order to be able to extract the complete *Mathematica* expressions:

```
text = Import["OSF Lab Report 1.m", "Lines"];

text2 = StringJoin[StringTrim[#, "(*" | "*)"] <> "\n" & /@ text];
```

Now we match complete expressions with `Head` `Image` using the regexp developed by [Xavier](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/31159/xavier) in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125498/280) post (I've simplified it for matching only balanced square braces `[]`):

```
images = StringCases[text2, 
   "Image" ~~ RegularExpression["(?P<a>\\[([^\\[\\]]|(?P>a))*\\])"]];
```

Now you can convert them directly into images:

```
ToExpression /@ images
```

All images except the last are converted successfully. The `ColorProfileData` of the last image contains damaged `CompressedData`, hence we have to remove the `ColorSpace` information completely in order to obtain a valid image:

```
code = ToHeldExpression[images[[-1]]];
Delete[code, {1, 3}] // ReleaseHold
```

The text without images can be obtained using the same regexp:

```
text3 = StringReplace[text2, 
 "Image" ~~ RegularExpression["(?P<a>\\[([^\\[\\]]|(?P>a))*\\])"] -> ""];
```

Now you can make an editable `Cell` containing all the text with things like `\[CapitalDelta]d` already properly formatted:

```
CellPrint[Cell[text3]]
```

(but things like `Subscript[L, 1]` you still have to format manually).

An alternative is to export it as a TXT file:

```
Export["OSF Lab Report 1 - Text Only.txt", text3]
```

The rest is up to you.

Comment: Am I to open a new mathematica notebook for this?

Comment: Thank you very much..
It still leaves work for be organised but otherwise the 'word texts' are still intact.
You guys are the heroes and best wishes!

Comment: However I see a "debug" on the toolbar of my file. Does that mean anything?

Comment: @Physkid Yes, you should create a new Notebook and manually paste fragments of text and images into it in order to re-create the original look of the Notebook you have lost. I have added some additional code at the bottom of the post which potentially can simplify your work.