# How to convert a string having nested parentheses into an expression?

Tags: import, string-manipulation, conversion, parsing, regular-expressions

I am a Wolfram Language/*Mathematica* beginner and trying to convert STEP ISO10303 commands into geometrical regions.
A simple command looks like

```
(vector(a,(b,c)),line(d,(e,f))
```

I tried with `String` commands to convert it into a valid `ToExpression` string like

```
{vector[a,{b,c}],line[d,{e,f}]}
```

allowing then to convert it with Rules into geometrical objects.

I managed to get a first prototype running but struggled finding a generic way of converting nested parentheses.

As I am a mediocre Perl programmer I would use the recipe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445674/can-i-use-perl-regular-expressions-to-match-balanced-text but I could not find information if Mathematica regex allows using longest match without backtracking and reference to sub-pattern?

Literature says that one either needs recursive regex usage or stack implementation when trying to parse nested objects.

Any help on how to tackle this problem is much appreciated.

Regards
Markus

Answer (score 12):

I'd do the minimum necessary to make a legitimate, unambiguous *Mathematica* expression, and then let *Mathematica* rewrite it.

```
stepexpr[s_] := ToExpression[StringReplace[s, {"(" -> " dummy[", ")" -> "]"}]] /.
op_Symbol dummy[args__] -> op[args] /. dummy -> List
```

This replaces `()` expressions with a `dummy[]` function in the string, making a legal expression. Then, in *Mathematica*, it transforms `op dummy[args]` into `op[args]`. Finally, it makes `List`s of the remaining `dummy` functions.

```
stepexpr["(vector(a,(b,c)),line(d,(e,f)))"]
(* {vector[a, {b, c}], line[d, {e, f}]} *)
```

Comment: Very clever! I am really impressed by the power of Mathematica. It is good that I can learn from all of you. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I saw another solution using Times=Sequence and tried to follow up on it with
inline `Block[{Times = Sequence},
 step = StringReplace["(vector(a,(b,c)))", {"(" -> "{", ")" -> "}"}] //
    ToExpression;
 step /. {w_, c_} :> w[c]
 ]`
Unfortunately I did not manage to  get this solution work with a list of commands like shown in my question. I experimented with Apply working on a pair of list but did not manage to get it run. May be you can show me how to do this.

Comment: `Sequence` is a rather peculiar object, and I don't know how to employ it to do what you want.

Answer (score 5):

In your example you need `[]` if and only if two letters precede.
If that fact extends to the generel case, then

```
ToExpression[With[{s1 = StringReplace[string, {
  a_ ~~ b_ ~~ "(" /; LetterQ[a] && LetterQ[b] :> a <> b <> "[",
  "(" -> "{"}]},
StringReplacePart[s1,
  StringCases[s1, {"[", "{"}] /. {"{" -> "}", "[" -> "]"},
  StringPosition[s1, ")"]]]]
```

> ```
> {vector[a, {b, c}], line[d, {e, f}]}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

In the case of that example:

```
str = "(vector(a,(b,c)),line(d,(e,f)))";
StringCases[str, {
  "vector(" ~~ Shortest[arg1__] ~~ ",(" ~~ Shortest[arg2__] ~~ "," ~~ Shortest[arg3__] ~~ "))" :> vector[arg1, {arg2, arg3}],
  "line(" ~~ Shortest[arg1__] ~~ ",(" ~~ Shortest[arg2__] ~~ "," ~~ Shortest[arg3__] ~~ "))" :> line[arg1, {arg2, arg3}]
  }]
```

> `{vector["a", {"b", "c"}], line["d", {"e", "f"}]}`

Feel free to tell me if this is not general enough or if there is another problem.

If you have lists of varying length so that you cannot encode it directly in the pattern:

```
StringCases[
 "f(a,b,c,d)",
 "f(" ~~ args__ ~~ ")" :> StringSplit[args, ","]
 ]
```

> `{{"a", "b", "c", "d"}}`

Answer (score 3):

Starting from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77808/280) great answer we can do this in two steps using recursive regular expressions:

```
str = "(vector(a,(b,c,vector(a,(b,c)))),line(d,(e,f)))";
sqBrPos = StringPosition[str, 
                WordBoundary ~~ RegularExpression@"(?P<a>\\(([^\\(\\)]|(?P>a))*\\))"];
str2 = StringReplacePart[StringReplacePart[str, "[", {#1, #1} & @@@ sqBrPos], 
                                                "]", {#2, #2} & @@@ sqBrPos]
curBrPos = StringPosition[str2, RegularExpression@"(?P<a>\\(([^\\(\\)]|(?P>a))*\\))"];
str3 = StringReplacePart[StringReplacePart[str2, "{", {#1, #1} & @@@ curBrPos], 
                                                 "}", {#2, #2} & @@@ curBrPos]
ToExpression[str3, InputForm, Hold]
```

> ```
> "(vector[a,(b,c,vector[a,(b,c)])],line[d,(e,f)])"
>
> "{vector[a,{b,c,vector[a,{b,c}]}],line[d,{e,f}]}"
>
> Hold[{vector[a, {b, c, vector[a, {b, c}]}], line[d, {e, f}]}]
> ```

Strongly related:

- [Match opening and closing parentheses?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77779/280)
- [How to get the longest bracket pairs from a string](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125391/280)
- [String matching balanced pairs of braces](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87329/280)
- [Does RegularExpression support "(?R)"?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72724/280)

Comment: Good to know that recursive regular expressions work. Do you know which regex engine is used in Mathematica as the Documentation Center is not stating that one can use ?P It looks to me like Perl with the fact that each backslash has to be escaped in Mathemitca.

Comment: @MarkusSonderegger *Mathematica* [uses the PCRE library](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html#274403895), which currently (starting from *Mathematica* version 10.1) supports [different styles for backreferences](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcresyntax.html#SEC20). You should read the official PCRE docs for the syntax. And yes, you must additionally escape every backslash inside of `RegularExpression`.

Comment: @MarkusSonderegger About escaping in `RegularExpression` you can be interested in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7378/280) answer.